# Sub _change reference of added comobox to userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

The following code will open a userform (examples) in which I have a commmandbutton which adds a new Combobox. I can name the combobox and can retrive the name in the immediate window, but I am unable to accecs the change command of the added combobox(es) or retrive the acces to their input.

In would like to do things upon change of this added combobox. I am able to do it for 1 box using the set "newgene1" = .... but than it on reclickit this first box will get lost.

[image: The userform example][image: User from after clickig button multiple times]

```
Option Explicit
Dim Counter As Integer
Private WithEvents newgene1 As MSForms.ComboBox
Private WithEvents newgene2 As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim Generanger As Range


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set Generanger = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)) 'list of data
    Generanger.Select
    Counter = 1
    cboGenelist.RowSource = Generanger.Address
End Sub

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub cboGenelist_Change()
    MsgBox (cboGenelist.Text)
End Sub

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub cmdAddgene_Click()
        
    UserForm1.Height = UserForm1.Height + 20
    
     UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.comboBox.1", "newgene" & Counter) = "select"
        With Me.Controls("newgene" & Counter)
            .Left = 20
            .Top = UserForm1.Height - 50
            .RowSource = Generanger.Address
            .Font.Name = "Trebuchet MS"
            .Font.Size = 12
        End With
    Debug.Print Me.Controls("newgene" & Counter).Name
    Counter = Counter + 1
End Sub

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub newgene1_Change()
   MsgBox (newgene.Text)
End Sub

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub newgene2_Change()
   MsgBox (newgene2.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is typically handled using a Control Array: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Yes, many thanks, as well for the quick response. I seem to get i working!